# How to divide a decimal number into rounded parts that add up to the original number?

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

All Decimal numbers are rounded to 2 digits when saved into application. I'm given a number `totalAmount` and asked to divide it into `n` equal parts(or close to equal).

Example :

```
Given : totalAmount = 421.9720; count = 2 (totalAmount saved into application is 421.97)
Expected : 210.99, 210.98 => sum = 421.97
Actual(with plain divide) : 210.9860 (210.99), 210.9860 (210.99) => sum = 412.98
```

My approach :

```
var totalAmount = 421.972m;
var count = 2;
var individualCharge = Math.Floor(totalAmount / count);
var leftOverAmount = totalAmount - (individualCharge * count);
for(var i = 0;i < count; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine(individualCharge + leftOverAmount); 
    leftOverAmount = 0;
}
```

This gives (-211.97, -210)

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://rextester.com/CGCQY68918).

Comment: Did you see a bug or are you trying to come up with an algorithm to split a number by given precision? Can you paste in your code for understanding?

Comment: @Saar I'm trying to come up with a algorithm that can solve my prob. I pasted my code which isn't much of a solution but just an attempt.

Comment: @ChloeAnderson Update post with my code.

Comment: Code doesn't compile. Datatypes not known.

Comment: @Llama Please check now

Comment: Code [_still_ doesn't compile](https://rextester.com/GVDZ12081). Please actually test it before posting it.

Comment: Please try now. I was trying to extract it from my original code.

Comment: @Reddy I've edited the title of your question to make it more descriptive. If it doesn't reflect your problem, feel free to edit it further.

Comment: That actually helps. Thank you (y) @41686d6564

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understand the question, but does changing the floor expression to `Math.Floor(totalAmount * 100 / count)/100` do what you want?

Answer (score 2):

```
public IEnumerable<decimal> GetDividedAmounts(decimal amount, int count)
{
    var pennies = (int)(amount * 100) % count;
    var baseAmount = Math.Floor((amount / count) * 100) / 100;
    
    foreach (var _ in Enumerable.Range(1, count))
    {
        var offset = pennies-- > 0 ? 0.01m : 0m;
        yield return baseAmount + offset;
    }
}
```

---

Feel free to alter this if you want to get an array or an IEnumerable which is not deferred. I updated it to get the baseAmount to be the floor value so it isn't recalculated within the loop.

Basically you need to find the base amount and a total of all the leftover pennies. Then, simply add the pennies back one by one until you run out. Because the pennies are based on the modulus operator, they'll always be in the range of [0, count - 1], so you'll never have a final leftover penny.

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Thank you Champ!

Answer (score 1):

You're introducing a few rounding errors here, then compounding them. This is a common problem with financial data, especially when you have to constrain your algorithm to only produce outputs with 2 decimal places. It's worse when dealing with actual money in countries where 1 cent/penny/whatever coins are no longer legal tender. At least when working with electronic money the rounding isn't as big an issue.

The naive approach of dividing the total by the count and rounding the results is, as you've already discovered, not going to work. What you need is some way to spread out the errors while varying the output amounts by no more than $0.01. No output value can be more than $0.01 from any other output value, and the total must be the truncated total value.

What you need is a way to distribute the error across the output values, with the smallest possible variation between the values in the result. The trick is to track your error and adjust the output down once the error is high enough. (This is basically how the Bresenham line-drawing algorithm figures out when to increase the `y` value, if that helps.)

Here's the generalized form, which is pretty quick:

```
public IEnumerable<decimal> RoundedDivide(decimal amount, int count)
{
    int totalCents = (int)Math.Floor(100 * amount);
    // work out the true division, integer portion and error values
    float div = totalCents / (float)count;
    int portion = (int)Math.Floor(div);
    float stepError = div - portion;

    float error = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        int value = portion;
        // add in the step error and see if we need to add 1 to the output
        error += stepError;
        if (error > 0.5)
        {
            value++;
            error -= 1;
        }
        // convert back to dollars and cents for outputput
        yield return value / 100M;
    }
}
```

I've tested it with `count` values from 1 through 100, all outputs sum to match the (floored) input value exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to break it down to steps:

```
            int decimals = 2;
            int factor = (int)Math.Pow(10, decimals);
            int count = 2;

            decimal totalAmount = 421.97232m;
            totalAmount = Math.Floor(totalAmount * factor) / factor;   // 421.97, you may want round here, depends on your requirement.

            int baseAmount = (int)(totalAmount * factor / count); // 42197 / 2 = 21098
            int left = (int)(totalAmount * factor) % count;  // 1

            //  Adding back the left for Mod operation
            for (int i = 0; i < left; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine((decimal)(baseAmount + 1) / factor); // 21098 + 1 / 100 = 210.99
            }

            // The reset that does not needs adjust
            for (int i = 0; i < count - left; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine((decimal)baseAmount / factor);    // 21098 / 100 = 210.98
            }
```